# Bootstrap 3 form-control class issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap 3. I have an issue with table colspan attribute in chrome only.As described in the bootstrap documentation that form-control class has 100% width, but when i applied it on the input box inside the colspan 2 than the width of input box is not 100%.

[Please check this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/eKoMaDIT/2/edit) (Issue with chrome only)

Whats the wrokaround?

Answer (score 2):

set the containing div width to 100% and it should fix the issue.

```
<tr>
     <td class="form-group" colspan="2">
       <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;"> <!--------right here-->
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">
       </i>
       </span>
       <input type="text" class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" />
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

also, might i ask why you're not using divs with class "rows" and "cols"?

Comment: But why it is not working on chrome, why extra setting is required for chrome ??

Comment: probably because you didn't explicitly defined your table's width. i see why. .input-group has display:table set in bootstrap.css

Comment: It looks to me as if Chrome is the only browser displaying it as defined.